# In Django how can I get a queryset of all the records that have a particular reverse relationship?

Tags: django

So, I have a data model simplified to this

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    title = models.TextField()
    ...

class Outcome(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...

class ActivityOutcome(models.Model):
    note = models.TextField()
    outcome = models.ManyToMany(Outcome)
    activity = models.ManyToMany(Activity)

class Organisation(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    outcomes = models.ManyToManyField(Outcome, related_name='outcome_organisation')
    ...

class Programme(models.Model 
    title = models.TextField()
    outcomes = models.ManyToMAnyField(Outcome, related_name='outcome_programme')
    ...
```

I want to have a single class of `ActivityOutcome` because it makes it much simpler to process, but I need to have some `Programme` Outcomes and some `Organisation` Outcomes. If I wanted a QuerySet of all "Programme" Outcomes, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`__isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) to filter all outcomes that have a related Programme.

```
outcomes = Outcome.objects.filter(outcome_programme__isnull=False)
```

If more than one programme can have the same outcome, you might need to use [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to prevent duplicates.

```
outcomes = Outcome.objects.filter(programme__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go.